# PHP polish letters as first element of array not displayed

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I've got an issue:
I have string `$title = "ŁAZIENKA"` and I need to convert it to: `<span>Ł</span>AZIENKA`.

I used tried to get the first element of string like this: `$first = $title[0]` and `$first = substr($title, 0, 1)`. In both cases `$first` equals "?".

I also tried some `utf8_encode()` and `mb_convert_ecncoding()`, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

For multibyte strings, you need to use the `mb_`-functions:

```
first = mb_substr($title, 0, 1)
```

It's best to use them all the time - except you can definitely rule out that multibyte character can be part of that string.